# Select2 and wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform not working together in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use Select2 in wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform. The first row is working fine but when I'm clicking on the plus button, the select2 fild keeps on spinning.
Screenshot - [image]. I've tried - https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform/issues/76 and https://github.com/TimNZ/yii2-dynamicform/blob/master/src/assets/yii2-dynamic-form.js it but seems not to be working.

My code in vendor/wbragance/yii2-dynamicform/asset/yii2-dynamic-form.js looks like -

```
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop"
        var $hasDepdrop = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-depdrop]');
        if ($hasDepdrop.length > 0) {
            $hasDepdrop.each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('select2') === undefined) {
                    $(this).removeData().off();
                    $(this).unbind();
                    _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                }
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2"
        var $hasSelect2 = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-select2]');
        if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
            $hasSelect2.each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));

                if ($(this).data('select2')) {
                    $(this).select2('destroy');
                }

                var configDepdrop = $(this).data('depdrop');
                if (configDepdrop) {
                    configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, configDepdrop);
                    $(this).removeData().off();
                    $(this).unbind();
                    _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                }
                var s2LoadingFunc = typeof initSelect2Loading != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                var s2OpenFunc = typeof initSelect2DropStyle != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(s2LoadingFunc(id, '.select2-container--krajee'));

                var kvClose = 'kv_close_' + id.replace(/\-/g, '_');

                $('#' + id).on('select2:opening', function(ev) {
                    s2OpenFunc(id, kvClose, ev);
                });

                $('#' + id).on('select2:unselect', function() {
                    window[kvClose] = true;
                });

               if (configDepdrop) {
                    var loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText) ? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
                    initDepdropS2(id, loadingText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**Update -**

```
I've changed the yii2-dynamic-form.js as following 
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop"
        var $hasDepdrop = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-depdrop]');
        if ($hasDepdrop.length > 0) {
            $hasDepdrop.each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('select2') === undefined) {
                    $(this).removeData().off();
                    $(this).unbind();
                    _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                }

            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2"
        var $hasSelect2 = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-select2]');
        if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
            $hasSelect2.each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));

                    if ($(this).data('select2')) {
                    $(this).select2('destroy');
                }

                var configDepdrop = $(this).data('depdrop');
                if (configDepdrop) {
                    configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, configDepdrop);
                    $(this).removeData().off();
                    $(this).unbind();
                    _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                }

                var s2LoadingFunc = typeof initSelect2Loading != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                var s2OpenFunc = typeof initSelect2DropStyle != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(initS2Loading(id, '.select2-container--krajee'));

                    var kvClose = 'kv_close_' + id.replace(/\-/g, '_');

                    $('#' + id).on('select2:opening', function(ev) {
                        //initSelect2DropStyle(id, kvClose, ev);
                        s2OpenFunc(id, kvClose, ev);
                });
                $('#' + id).on('select2:unselect', function() {
                    window[kvClose] = true;
                });

                if (configDepdrop) {
                    var loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText) ? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
                    initDepdropS2(id, loadingText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Now the there's no error message but I get the following screen - 
[image]

I'm using Kartik Depdrop and Select2. Only in the first row both seems to be working. In the later only select2 is working with a spinning sign on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

### Here's my solution:

I've modified the dynamic-form.js as follows:

```
/**
 * yii2-dynamic-form
 *
 * A jQuery plugin to clone form elements in a nested manner, maintaining accessibility.
 *
 * @author Wanderson Bragança <wanderson.wbc@gmail.com>
 */
(function ($) {
    var pluginName = 'yiiDynamicForm';

    var regexID = /^(.+?)([-\d-]{1,})(.+)$/i;

    var regexName = /(^.+?)([\[\d{1,}\]]{1,})(\[.+\]$)/i;

    $.fn.yiiDynamicForm = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.yiiDynamicForm');
            return false;
        }
    };

    var events = {
        beforeInsert: 'beforeInsert',
        afterInsert: 'afterInsert',
        beforeDelete: 'beforeDelete',
        afterDelete: 'afterDelete',
        limitReached: 'limitReached'
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function (widgetOptions) {
            return this.each(function () {
                widgetOptions.template = _parseTemplate(widgetOptions);
            });
        },

        addItem: function (widgetOptions, e, $elem) {
           _addItem(widgetOptions, e, $elem);
        },

        deleteItem: function (widgetOptions, e, $elem) {
           _deleteItem(widgetOptions, e, $elem);
        },

        updateContainer: function () {
            var widgetOptions = eval($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));
            _updateAttributes(widgetOptions);
            _restoreSpecialJs(widgetOptions);
            _fixFormValidaton(widgetOptions);
        }
    };

    var _parseTemplate = function(widgetOptions) {

        var $template = $(widgetOptions.template);
        $template.find('div[data-dynamicform]').each(function(){
            var widgetOptions = eval($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));
            if ($(widgetOptions.widgetItem).length > 1) {
                var item = $(this).find(widgetOptions.widgetItem).first()[0].outerHTML;
                $(this).find(widgetOptions.widgetBody).html(item);
            }
        });

        $template.find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });

        $template.find('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
            var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
            var $inputHidden = $template.find('input[type="hidden"][name="' + inputName + '"]').first();
            if ($inputHidden) {
                $(this).val(1);
                $inputHidden.val(0);
            }
        });

        return $template;
    };

    var _getWidgetOptionsRoot = function(widgetOptions) {
        return eval($(widgetOptions.widgetBody).parents('div[data-dynamicform]').last().attr('data-dynamicform'));
    };

    var _getLevel = function($elem) {
        var level = $elem.parents('div[data-dynamicform]').length;
        level = (level < 0) ? 0 : level;
        return level;
    };

    var _count = function($elem, widgetOptions) {
        return $elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).find(widgetOptions.widgetItem).length;
    };

    var _createIdentifiers = function(level) {
        return new Array(level + 2).join('0').split('');
    };

    var _addItem = function(widgetOptions, e, $elem) {
        var count = _count($elem, widgetOptions);

        if (count < widgetOptions.limit) {
            $toclone = widgetOptions.template;
            $newclone = $toclone.clone(false, false);

            if (widgetOptions.insertPosition === 'top') {
                $elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).find(widgetOptions.widgetBody).prepend($newclone);
            } else {
                $elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).find(widgetOptions.widgetBody).append($newclone);
            }

            _updateAttributes(widgetOptions);
            _restoreSpecialJs(widgetOptions);
            _fixFormValidaton(widgetOptions);
            $elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).triggerHandler(events.afterInsert, $newclone);
        } else {
            // trigger a custom event for hooking
            $elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).triggerHandler(events.limitReached, widgetOptions.limit);
        }
    };

    var _removeValidations = function($elem, widgetOptions, count) {
        if (count > 1) {
            $elem.find('div[data-dynamicform]').each(function() {
                var currentWidgetOptions = eval($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));
                var level           = _getLevel($(this));
                var identifiers     = _createIdentifiers(level);
                var numItems        = $(this).find(currentWidgetOptions.widgetItem).length;

                for (var i = 1; i <= numItems -1; i++) {
                    var aux = identifiers;
                    aux[level] = i;
                    currentWidgetOptions.fields.forEach(function(input) {
                        var id = input.id.replace("{}", aux.join('-'));
                        if ($("#" + currentWidgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("find", id) !== "undefined") {
                            $("#" + currentWidgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("remove", id);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            var level          = _getLevel($elem.closest('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer));
            var widgetOptionsRoot       = _getWidgetOptionsRoot(widgetOptions);
            var identifiers    = _createIdentifiers(level);
            identifiers[0]     = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).length - 1;
            identifiers[level] = count - 1;

            widgetOptions.fields.forEach(function(input) {
                var id = input.id.replace("{}", identifiers.join('-'));
                if ($("#" + widgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("find", id) !== "undefined") {
                    $("#" + widgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("remove", id);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    var _deleteItem = function(widgetOptions, e, $elem) {
        var count = _count($elem, widgetOptions);

        if (count > widgetOptions.min) {
            $todelete = $elem.closest(widgetOptions.widgetItem);

            // trigger a custom event for hooking
            var eventResult = $('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).triggerHandler(events.beforeDelete, $todelete);
            if (eventResult !== false) {
                _removeValidations($todelete, widgetOptions, count);
                $todelete.remove();
                _updateAttributes(widgetOptions);
                _restoreSpecialJs(widgetOptions);
                _fixFormValidaton(widgetOptions);
                $('.' + widgetOptions.widgetContainer).triggerHandler(events.afterDelete);
            }
        }
    };

    var _updateAttrID = function($elem, index) {
        var widgetOptions = eval($elem.closest('div[data-dynamicform]').attr('data-dynamicform'));
        var id            = $elem.attr('id');
        var newID         = id;

        if (id !== undefined) {
            var matches = id.match(regexID);
            if (matches && matches.length === 4) {
                matches[2] = matches[2].substring(1, matches[2].length - 1);
                var identifiers = matches[2].split('-');
                identifiers[0] = index;

                if (identifiers.length > 1) {
                    var widgetsOptions = [];
                    $elem.parents('div[data-dynamicform]').each(function(i){
                        widgetsOptions[i] = eval($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));
                    });

                    widgetsOptions = widgetsOptions.reverse();
                    for (var i = identifiers.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                        identifiers[i] = $elem.closest(widgetsOptions[i].widgetItem).index();
                    }
                }

                newID = matches[1] + '-' + identifiers.join('-') + '-' + matches[3];
                $elem.attr('id', newID);
            } else {
                newID = id + index;
                $elem.attr('id', newID);
            }
        }

        if (id !== newID) {
            $elem.closest(widgetOptions.widgetItem).find('.field-' + id).each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('field-' + id).addClass('field-' + newID);
            });
            // update "for" attribute
            $elem.closest(widgetOptions.widgetItem).find("label[for='" + id + "']").attr('for',newID); 
        }

        return newID;
    };

    var _updateAttrName = function($elem, index) {
        var name = $elem.attr('name');

        if (name !== undefined) {
            var matches = name.match(regexName);

            if (matches && matches.length === 4) {
                matches[2] = matches[2].replace(/\]\[/g, "-").replace(/\]|\[/g, '');
                var identifiers = matches[2].split('-');
                identifiers[0] = index;

                if (identifiers.length > 1) {
                    var widgetsOptions = [];
                    $elem.parents('div[data-dynamicform]').each(function(i){
                        widgetsOptions[i] = eval($(this).attr('data-dynamicform'));
                    });

                    widgetsOptions = widgetsOptions.reverse();
                    for (var i = identifiers.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                        identifiers[i] = $elem.closest(widgetsOptions[i].widgetItem).index();
                    }
                }

                name = matches[1] + '[' + identifiers.join('][') + ']' + matches[3];
                $elem.attr('name', name);
            }
        }

        return name;
    };

    var _updateAttributes = function(widgetOptions) {
        var widgetOptionsRoot = _getWidgetOptionsRoot(widgetOptions);

        $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).each(function(index) {
            var $item = $(this);
            $(this).find('*').each(function() {
                // update "id" attribute
                _updateAttrID($(this), index);

                // update "name" attribute
                _updateAttrName($(this), index);
            });
        });
    };

    var _fixFormValidatonInput = function(widgetOptions, attribute, id, name) {
        if (attribute !== undefined) {
            attribute           = $.extend(true, {}, attribute);
            attribute.id        = id;
            attribute.container = ".field-" + id;
            attribute.input     = "#" + id;
            attribute.name      = name;
            attribute.value     = $("#" + id).val();
            attribute.status    = 0;

            if ($("#" + widgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("find", id) !== "undefined") {
                $("#" + widgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("remove", id);
            }

            $("#" + widgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("add", attribute);
        }
    };

    var _fixFormValidaton = function(widgetOptions) {
        var widgetOptionsRoot = _getWidgetOptionsRoot(widgetOptions);

        $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetBody).find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
            var id   = $(this).attr('id');
            var name = $(this).attr('name');

            if (id !== undefined && name !== undefined) {
                currentWidgetOptions = eval($(this).closest('div[data-dynamicform]').attr('data-dynamicform'));
                var matches = id.match(regexID);

                if (matches && matches.length === 4) {
                    matches[2]      = matches[2].substring(1, matches[2].length - 1);
                    var level       = _getLevel($(this));
                    var identifiers = _createIdentifiers(level -1);
                    var baseID      = matches[1] + '-' + identifiers.join('-') + '-' + matches[3];
                    var attribute   = $("#" + currentWidgetOptions.formId).yiiActiveForm("find", baseID);
                    _fixFormValidatonInput(currentWidgetOptions, attribute, id, name);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    var _restoreSpecialJs = function(widgetOptions) {
        var widgetOptionsRoot = _getWidgetOptionsRoot(widgetOptions);

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker"
        var $hasDatepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-datepicker]');
        if ($hasDatepicker.length > 0) {
            $hasDatepicker.each(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeData().datepicker('remove');
                $(this).parent().datepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-datepicker')));
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker"
        var $hasTimepicker = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-timepicker]');
        if ($hasTimepicker.length > 0) {
            $hasTimepicker.each(function() {
                $(this).removeData().off();
                $(this).parent().find('.bootstrap-timepicker-widget').remove();
                $(this).unbind();
                $(this).timepicker(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-timepicker')));
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-money"
        var $hasMaskmoney = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-maskMoney]');
        if ($hasMaskmoney.length > 0) {
            $hasMaskmoney.each(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('input').removeData().off();
                var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
                var displayID  = id + '-disp';
                $(displayID).maskMoney('destroy');
                $(displayID).maskMoney(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-maskMoney')));
                $(displayID).maskMoney('mask', parseFloat($(id).val()));
                $(displayID).on('change', function () {
                    var numDecimal = $(displayID).maskMoney('unmasked')[0];
                    $(id).val(numDecimal);
                    $(id).trigger('change');
                });
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput"
        var $hasFileinput = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-fileinput]');
        if ($hasFileinput.length > 0) {
            $hasFileinput.each(function() {
                $(this).fileinput(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-fileinput')));
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-touchspin"
        var $hasTouchSpin = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-TouchSpin]');
        if ($hasTouchSpin.length > 0) {
            $hasTouchSpin.each(function() {
                $(this).TouchSpin('destroy');
                $(this).TouchSpin(eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-TouchSpin')));
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput"
        var $hasSpectrum = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-spectrum]');
        if ($hasSpectrum.length > 0) {
            $hasSpectrum.each(function() {
                var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
                var sourceID  = id + '-source';
                $(sourceID).spectrum('destroy');
                $(sourceID).unbind();
                $(id).unbind();
                var configSpectrum = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-spectrum'));
                configSpectrum.change = function (color) {
                    jQuery(id).val(color.toString());
                };
                $(sourceID).attr('name', $(sourceID).attr('id'));
                $(sourceID).spectrum(configSpectrum);
                $(sourceID).spectrum('set', jQuery(id).val());
                $(id).on('change', function(){
                    $(sourceID).spectrum('set', jQuery(id).val());
                });
            });
        }

        var _restoreKrajeeDepdrop = function($elem) {
            var configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, eval($elem.attr('data-krajee-depdrop')));
            var inputID = $elem.attr('id');
            var matchID = inputID.match(regexID);

            if (matchID && matchID.length === 4) {
                for (index = 0; index < configDepdrop.depends.length; ++index) {
                    var match = configDepdrop.depends[index].match(regexID);
                    if (match && match.length === 4) {
                        configDepdrop.depends[index] = match[1] + matchID[2] + match[3];
                    }
                }
            }
            $elem.depdrop(configDepdrop);
        };

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop"
        var _restoreKrajeeDepdrop = function($elem) {
            var configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, eval($elem.attr('data-krajee-depdrop')));
            var inputID = $elem.attr('id');
            var matchID = inputID.match(regexID);

            if (matchID && matchID.length === 4) {
                for (index = 0; index < configDepdrop.depends.length; ++index) {
                    var match = configDepdrop.depends[index].match(regexID);
                    if (match && match.length === 4) {
                        configDepdrop.depends[index] = match[1] + matchID[2] + match[3];
                    }
                }
            }
            $elem.depdrop(configDepdrop);
        };
        var $hasDepdrop = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-depdrop]');
        if ($hasDepdrop.length > 0) {
            $hasDepdrop.each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('select2') === undefined) {
                     $(this).removeData().off();
                     $(this).unbind();
                     _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                  }
                var configDepdrop = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-depdrop'));
                $(this).depdrop(configDepdrop);
            });
        }

        // "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2"
        var $hasSelect2 = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-select2]');
        if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
            $hasSelect2.each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));
                $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(initS2Loading(id));
                $('#' + id).on('select2-open', function() {
                    initSelect2DropStyle(id)
                });
                if ($(this).attr('data-krajee-depdrop')) {
                    $(this).on('depdrop.beforeChange', function(e,i,v) {
                        var configDepdrop = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-depdrop'));
                        var loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText)? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
                        $('#' + id).select2('data', {text: loadingText});
                    });
                    $(this).on('depdrop.change', function(e,i,v,c) {
                        $('#' + id).select2('val', $('#' + id).val());
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };

})(window.jQuery);
```

### It's working well on my end.

[image: working well on my end]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to remove the spinning icon on the select2. I've removed the 'id' from select2 widget in my _form and that resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing changes in vendor's code there is new repo with issue fixes.

`Link => https://packagist.org/packages/vivekmarakana/yii2-dynamicform`

Either run

> **php composer.phar require --prefer-dist vivekmarakana/yii2-dynamicform "*"**

or add

> **"vivekmarakana/yii2-dynamicform": "*"**

to the require section of your composer.json file.